# Does a vector space with dimension 1 have an orthogonal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Normally an orthogonal basis of a finite vector space is referred as a basis that contains many vectors, i.e. 2 or more.

Consider a vector space that its dimension is 1 - does it have an orthogonal basis?
Is it true to refer to all the bases of that vector space as "orthogonal"?

I didn't find a reference for that [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_basis).

Comment: Indeed, that WP article on orthogonal basis is very stubby and does not discuss existence at all. However, the [Gram-Schmidt process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) works in any finite dimensional inner product space, including dimension 1 (and even 0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. Any basis for a one dimensional inner product space is an orthogonal basis because the orthogonality condition is [vacuously true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), i.e. there are no pairs which must be orthogonal.

Comment: The same applies to zero-dimensional space, "even more vacuously".

Comment: does any real number is the orthogonal basis for the real line, but only $\{1\}$ is the orthonormal basis?

Comment: @LJNG: $\{a\}$ is not an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R}$ for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$. By the answer above, it is an orthogonal basis if and only if it is a basis. For which $a$ is $\{a\}$ a basis of $\mathbb{R}$. Also, $\{1\}$ is not the only orthonormal basis.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese thank you for your reply. Would you please enlighten me a bit more. if $a\neq0$ and isn't $\{a\},a\in\mathbb{R}$ orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R}$?and also why isn't $\{1\}$ not the only orthonormal basis? isn't that has to be length $1$

Comment: @LJNG: In your initial comment, you asked if any real number forms an orthogonal basis and the answer was no, precisely because you hadn't ruled out $0$. As for the orthonormal basis, there are other real numbers with length $1$.